# SAPUI5 Filling SmartTable with OData from XMII

Tags: javascript, xml, odata, sapui5

I'm currently trying to fill a Smart Table (xml view) with OData from our MII server.
I keep getting the following errors:

Error: resource *PATH*/Component-changes.json could not be loaded from ./Component-changes.json. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors. Reason: Not Found -
'getChanges' failed: -

This is my Main.controller.js:

```
sap.ui.controller("PATH.view.Main", {

/**
* Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
* Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
* @memberOf sapui5.Main
*/
onInit: function() {
    var oModel, oView;
    this.oUpdateFinishedDeferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    this.getView().byId("main").attachEventOnce("updateFinished", function(){
        this.oUpdateFinishedDeferred.resolve();
    }, this);
         sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).attachRouteMatched(this.onRouteMatched , this);

    var oModel, oView;
    oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("http://server:port/XMII/IlluminatorOData/QueryTemplate?QueryTemplate=MessageMonitor%2FTemplates%2FQuery%2FMIILogDetailsQry&Content-Type=text%2Fxml", {annotationURI: "/XMII/IlluminatorOData/$metadata"});

    jQuery.sap.log.error(oModel.getMetaModel());
    oModel.setCountSupported(false);
    var oTable = this.getView().byId("oTable");
    oTable.setEntitySet("Messages");
    oTable.setModel(oModel);
    oView = this.getView();
    oView.setModel(oModel);
    oTable.rebindTable();
},
onRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {
     var oList = this.getView().byId("main");
     var sName = oEvent.getParameter("name");
     var oArguments = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
    // Wait for the list to be loaded once
     jQuery.when(this.oUpdateFinishedDeferred).then(jQuery.proxy(function() {
     var aItems;
         // On the empty hash select the first item
         if (sName === "main") {
             //this.selectDetail();
         }
         // Try to select the item in the list
         if (sName === "product") {
             aItems = oList.getItems();
             for (var i = 0; i < aItems.length; i++) {
                 if (aItems[i].getBindingContext().getPath() === "/" +
                         oArguments.product) {
                     oList.setSelectedItem(aItems[i], true);
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
     }, this));
},
});
```

I'm developing on the server itself so I have no issues with the CORS errors I would get otherwise.

My Main.view.xml:

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:smartFilterBar="sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar" xmlns:smartTable="sap.ui.comp.smarttable" controllerName="PATH.view.Main" height="100%" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1">
<Page id="main" title="{i18n>PageTitle}" showNavButton="false">
<Toolbar></Toolbar>
    <content>
    <smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="smartFilterBar" entityType="Messages" persistencyKey="SmartFilter_Explored">
    <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>            
      <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="CATEGORY">
      <smartFilterBar:defaultFilterValues>
          <smartFilterBar:SelectOption low="i">
          </smartFilterBar:SelectOption>
        </smartFilterBar:defaultFilterValues>
      </smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>          
      <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="DATETIME">
        <smartFilterBar:defaultFilterValues>
            <smartFilterBar:SelectOption low="2014">
            </smartFilterBar:SelectOption>
          </smartFilterBar:defaultFilterValues>
        </smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
      </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>          
    </smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>

        <smartTable:SmartTable id="oTable" entitySet="Messages" 
        smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" tableType="Table" 
        useExportToExcel="false" useVariantManagement="false" 
        useTablePersonalisation="false" header="Messages" 
        showRowCount="false" 
        persistencyKey="SmartTableAnalytical_Explored" 
        enableAutoBinding="true" />
    </content>
</Page>
```

My Component.js, index.html and MyRouter.js are setup according to the SAP Hana step by step guide for your first application.

I'm completely clueless on what the issue might be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know you've set useVariantManagement to false, but check the Setup section of this link to see if you can get it to start pulling: http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/a8/e55aa2f8bc4127923b20685a6d1621/content.htm?frameset=/en/EF/1EB51B768D42708E3F1DE8EC0D5139/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/e4/843b8c3d05411c83f58033bac7f072/plain.htm&node_id=659

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up doing something entirely else due to the fact the metadata wasn't the right data I needed for the Smart-Table. Thanks for the answers to the question.

I've created a default table in my controller, which I filled with the columns I needed and wanted. And I've bound my rows to the columns.

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table();
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({label: "{i18n>Category}", editable: false,
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField( {
            value: {
                path: "CATEGORY",
                formatter: sap.ui.demo.table.util.Formatter.label,
            },
            editable : false,
        }), sortProperty: "Category" }));
 // more addColumn lines...
oTable.setSelectionMode(sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single); // Single select mode.
oTable.bindRows({ // bind the rows to the odata model.
    path: '/Rowset(QueryTemplate=\'MessageMonitor/Templates/Query/UniqueGUIDs\',RowsetId=\'1\')/Row',
});
this.getView().byId("idIconTabBar").insertContent(oTable); // add the table to the icontabbar
```

Answer (score 0):

The file component-changes.json is read for Variant Management but this should not prevent the data in smart table from loading.  And since you have set enableAutoBinding does the system make a call to your Service/Messages?